# Are the kids from Captain Planet actually the Magic School Bus kids?

Tags: captain-planet, the-magic-school-bus

Firstly I apologise if this isn't really the right place to post this question but it was the best place I could think of.

I've seen this meme before around the internet for years but I just wanted to know if it was purely coincidence or if the design of the characters between the two cartoons actually had any relevance?

All 5 characters match the same race and gender and that seems like too much of a coincidence. There must be some reason, if only subtle for why they match EXACTLY?

[image]

Comment: “I apologise if this isn't really the right place to post this question” — looks entirely on-topic to me.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Oh good! Hopefully someone can shine some light on this question :)

Comment: Confirmation bias, [there's a few more children in _The Magic School Bus_](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-B2xhPH_cF78/UDJksvdb8xI/AAAAAAAAP3I/KkoT9HUj5bc/s1600/magicbus.jpg)

Comment: @Izkata Ah! I never new this. I watched it a few times as a kid but just assumed the kids 5 was the total

Comment: @Izkata The image you shared is presumably from one of the books. "In some of the books and on the TV series, Arnold has orange hair, but he has blond hair in the computer games and other books." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Magic_School_Bus_characters#Arnold_Matthew_Perlstein))

Comment: Its multiculturalism, the nineties were all about excepting all races and creeds

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Yeah, I thought it looked off - I've only seen the TV series, and the one with the "R" shirt also looks wrong to me.  It was just a quick find from Google Images that has all of them

Comment: @giacomocasanova I believe you mean "accepting" and not "excepting".  Though "excepting" makes it much funnier.

Comment: @Skeletank. Yeah it does, bravo for picking up on that

Comment: Hehe. While researching another question I spotted how similar the kids were, then went onto google to find out if the two companies were related, only to wind up back here again on this question :-)

Comment: @Richard it's a vicious circle

Comment: also it is weird that the kids develop strong accents all of a sudden

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## No. The Planeteers never knew each other before being summoned by Gaia.

In the very first episode, you meet each of the Planeteers on their respective continents. There are numerous references to their backgrounds throughout the series, and it is never established that they went to the same school as children.

As for the similarities, the producers may have done it on purpose, however its more the case they were both going for a diverse group of people.

- Groups of 5 are big enough to allow wide diversity, but not so large as its difficult to differentiate.
- Africans, Native Americans and Asian are both genetically predisposed to black hair. Asian hair is especially straight as both illustrations show.
- Left with an option for a brunette and a blonde Caucasian, they would have wanted the blonde female character as blondeness is an attractive trait in women.

Any other similarities are coincidental as [Magic School Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_School_Bus_%28TV_series%29) and [Captain Planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Planet_and_the_Planeteers) were produced by different companies.

Comment: Didn't think they were related but it just seemed like too much of a coincidence one their appearance.

Comment: It's not a coincidence. Both groups fit the [Five-Token Band Trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FiveTokenBand) (warning: TV Tropes link).

Comment: @phantom42 Just curious why you warn about the TV Tropes link. That's the second link to that site that I've seen here (but I've only been on this SE site since yesterday), and I had never encountered the site before yesterday. So what's up with the warning?

Comment: @TreborRude [TV Tropes Will Ruin Your Life](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife) (warning: TV Tropes link).

Comment: @TreborRude In addition to the meta-trope ssell mentioned, it's sort of a joke/thing here that anytime we link to TV Tropes, we add a little warning. It's just *waaay* too easy to click through and then find that you've spent a week stumbling through the site.

Comment: Ah, I see, the same sort of thing that can happen any time you go to Wikipedia or IMDB. :-)

Comment: @phantom42 you just ruined stargate for me. lol